# How to translate a pandas group by without aggregation to pyspark?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I am trying to convert the following pandas line into pyspark:

```
df = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).head(1)
```

Now, I am familiar with the pyspark `df.groupby("col1", "col2")` method in pyspark, as well as the following to get whatever the first element is within a group:

```
df = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("SOME_DATE_COLUMN"))).where(col("row_num") < 2)
```

However, without an `orderBy` argument, this grouping and fetching of the first element in each group doesn't work (and I am literally trying to convert from pandas to spark, whatever the pandas line does):

> An error occurred while calling o2547.withColumn.
>   : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function row_number() >requires window to be ordered, please add ORDER BY clause. For example >SELECT row_number()(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition >ORDER BY window_ordering) from table

Looking at the pandas groupby documentation, I cannot grasp what groupby does without a following sort/agg function applied to the groups; i.e. what is the default order within a group from which the $.head(1)$ fetches the first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the order of your pandas dataframe before the groupby. From the pandas groupby [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> Sort group keys. Get better performance by turning this off. Note this does not influence the order of observations within each group. **Groupby preserves the order of rows within each group.**

Converting the pandas beheaviour exactly to pyspark is impossible as pyspark dataframes aren't [ordered](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207). But if your data source can provide a row number or something like that, it is possible.